# Error pay invoice. Ran out of routes to try after 2 attempts: see paystatus

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning

I wanted to send some satoshis on testnet lightning network but I got "Ran out of routes to try after 2 attempts: see paystatus" error.

I have a channel with 02...48 (1ML.com node ALPHA) and created the invoice on starblocks.acinq.co.

I think the error was caused due to path finding error but how can I solve it? What is this situation? Do we need to connect another peer and fund it again?

I use c-lightning v0.7.0

I'm now trying to "see paystatus" but no idea now.

```
$ lightning-cli getinfo
{
   "id" : "03f3d6374d7ce81de33f5a671c32531abb3d0a9195de1027ffea5f99bae8e3e40e",
   "alias" : "ZONOCLNTEST1",
   "color" : "008000",
   "num_peers" : 1,

$ lightning-cli listpeers
{
   "peers" : [
      {
         "id" : "02312627fdf07fbdd7e5ddb136611bdde9b00d26821d14d94891395452f67af248",
         "connected" : true,
         "netaddr" : [
            "23.237.77.12:9735"
         ],

$ lightning-cli listfunds
{
   "outputs" : [
      {
         "txid" : "6a7682cbce618459b3356ceeef186e4da1d1634e8b45330a3afaec0a5f9e8508",
         "output" : 1,
         "value" : 102777,
         "amount_msat" : "102777000msat",
         "address" : "tb1qpvc7y83jvsnc5hxhx3lqv6kpwd8z4e2muw0wkd",
         "status" : "confirmed"
      }
   ],
   "channels" : [
      {
         "peer_id" : "02312627fdf07fbdd7e5ddb136611bdde9b00d26821d14d94891395452f67af248",
         "short_channel_id" : "1542251x49x0",
         "channel_sat" : 20000,
         "our_amount_msat" : "20000000msat",
         "channel_total_sat" : 20000,
         "amount_msat" : "20000000msat",
         "funding_txid" : "6a7682cbce618459b3356ceeef186e4da1d1634e8b45330a3afaec0a5f9e8508"
      }
   ]
}

// created this invoice on starblocks.acinq.co
$ lightning-cli pay lntb12u1pw077szpp5f6w9huglw7gv9aefqrnehms7rg9qrss6l454agg6nfs2r8sclytqdp2xys9xct5da3kx6twv9kk7m3qg3hkccm9ypxxzar5v5cqp5kqk36jz2fdqxnqs4hmnpcyfcwt7dj3s0969nlv3ulwpuxjpeql9pgrpys9sar0kx2ge028w3lceccdgg920dc9ml3c3u9gr0vc9r5qgqdydp02
{
   "code" : 210,
   "message" : "Ran out of routes to try after 2 attempts: see paystatus"
}

// error log
2019-06-11T09:53:21.973Z lightningd(1): Sending 1201001msat over 2 hops to deliver 1200000msat
2019-06-11T09:53:22.933Z lightningd(1): 02312627fdf07fbdd7e5ddb136611bdde9b00d26821d14d94891395452f67af248 chan #1: htlc 1 failed from 0th node with code 0x1007 (WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE)

// lightningd version
lightningd v0.7.0-525-g9e511cb
```

---

Update 1

```
$ lightning-cli listpeers
{
   "peers" : [
      {
         "id" : "02312627fdf07fbdd7e5ddb136611bdde9b00d26821d14d94891395452f67af248",
         "connected" : true,
         "netaddr" : [
            "23.237.77.12:9735"
         ],
         "globalfeatures" : "",
         "localfeatures" : "82",
         "channels" : [
            {
               "state" : "CHANNELD_NORMAL",
               "scratch_txid" : "f980a7958990c6475f59b3c27a91a75f0ccd5f367c80fbefd99e4d3e0ecaf4f5",
               "owner" : "lightning_channeld",
               "short_channel_id" : "1542251x49x0",
               "direction" : 1,
               "channel_id" : "08859e5f0aecfa3a0a33458b4e63d1a14d6e18efee6c35b3598461cecb82766a",
               "funding_txid" : "6a7682cbce618459b3356ceeef186e4da1d1634e8b45330a3afaec0a5f9e8508",
               "private" : false,
               "funding_allocation_msat" : {
                  "02312627fdf07fbdd7e5ddb136611bdde9b00d26821d14d94891395452f67af248" : 0,
                  "03f3d6374d7ce81de33f5a671c32531abb3d0a9195de1027ffea5f99bae8e3e40e" : 20000000
               },
               "funding_msat" : {
                  "02312627fdf07fbdd7e5ddb136611bdde9b00d26821d14d94891395452f67af248" : "0msat",
                  "03f3d6374d7ce81de33f5a671c32531abb3d0a9195de1027ffea5f99bae8e3e40e" : "20000000msat"
               },
               "msatoshi_to_us" : 20000000,
               "to_us_msat" : "20000000msat",
               "msatoshi_to_us_min" : 20000000,
               "min_to_us_msat" : "20000000msat",
               "msatoshi_to_us_max" : 20000000,
               "max_to_us_msat" : "20000000msat",
               "msatoshi_total" : 20000000,
               "total_msat" : "20000000msat",
               "dust_limit_satoshis" : 546,
               "dust_limit_msat" : "546000msat",
               "max_htlc_value_in_flight_msat" : 18446744073709551615,
               "max_total_htlc_in_msat" : "18446744073709551615msat",
               "their_channel_reserve_satoshis" : 546,
               "their_reserve_msat" : "546000msat",
               "our_channel_reserve_satoshis" : 546,
               "our_reserve_msat" : "546000msat",
               "spendable_msatoshi" : 19454000,
               "spendable_msat" : "19454000msat",
               "htlc_minimum_msat" : 0,
               "minimum_htlc_in_msat" : "0msat",
               "their_to_self_delay" : 6,
               "our_to_self_delay" : 144,
               "max_accepted_htlcs" : 483,
               "status" : [
                  "CHANNELD_NORMAL:Reconnected, and reestablished.",
                  "CHANNELD_NORMAL:Funding transaction locked. Channel announced."
               ],
               "in_payments_offered" : 0,
               "in_msatoshi_offered" : 0,
               "in_offered_msat" : "0msat",
               "in_payments_fulfilled" : 0,
               "in_msatoshi_fulfilled" : 0,
               "in_fulfilled_msat" : "0msat",
               "out_payments_offered" : 2,
               "out_msatoshi_offered" : 2402002,
               "out_offered_msat" : "2402002msat",
               "out_payments_fulfilled" : 0,
               "out_msatoshi_fulfilled" : 0,
               "out_fulfilled_msat" : "0msat",
               "htlcs" : []
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

---

Update 3

I tried it again then it worked.

Before doing that I deleted my lighting data folder and restarted it. Then I did the same process as the previous one.

One different things is that I connected another node because building node topology was stopped. (I got not found route error)

I don't know why I got the error at the first time. The lightningd is running in docker in my local Mac so I think this might be the cause...? (not sure but it could be being sleep mode after connecting channel.)

Anyways, the problem was solved. thank you.

```
$  lightning-cli listpeers
{
   "peers" : [
      {
         "id" : "02312627fdf07fbdd7e5ddb136611bdde9b00d26821d14d94891395452f67af248",
         "connected" : true,
         "netaddr" : [
            "23.237.77.12:9735"
         ],
         "globalfeatures" : "",
         "localfeatures" : "82",
         "channels" : [
            {
               "state" : "CHANNELD_NORMAL",
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id" : "03f44acc1df8639efbe5099da403f213a4ce5bbe6f9bdac7bfa26dcc338761e9de",
         "connected" : true,
         "netaddr" : [
            "207.154.224.115:9735"
         ],
         "globalfeatures" : "",
         "localfeatures" : "81",
         "channels" : []
      }
   ]
}
```

```
$ lightning-cli pay lntb12u1pw0ljy4pp55mjg93fckm3ydxsdglp4xxtc8vuc0v79g24gm3rz8h72j8fg32tqdp2xys9xct5da3kx6twv9kk7m3qg3hkccm9ypxxzar5v5cqp5336eqcvsmkx9507p6r82ekralj82jl3npv0v2k8auj2kkgmc9l68mmmzkxvpcnzd3feyygp8hw6wq2qup6f97zfjlm2hzhlk4a9veegqstahde
{
   "id" : 1,
   "payment_hash" : "a6e482c538b6e2469a0d47c35319783b3987b3c542aa8dc4623dfca91d288a96",
   "destination" : "03933884aaf1d6b108397e5efe5c86bcf2d8ca8d2f700eda99db9214fc2712b134",
   "msatoshi" : 1200000,
   "amount_msat" : "1200000msat",
   "msatoshi_sent" : 1201035,
   "amount_sent_msat" : "1201035msat",
   "created_at" : 1560268918,
   "status" : "complete",
   "payment_preimage" : "c718e470dcf429280c611afba095c7396e219d60e590c6ee6beca8042f616483",
   "bolt11" : "lntb12u1pw0ljy4pp55mjg93fckm3ydxsdglp4xxtc8vuc0v79g24gm3rz8h72j8fg32tqdp2xys9xct5da3kx6twv9kk7m3qg3hkccm9ypxxzar5v5cqp5336eqcvsmkx9507p6r82ekralj82jl3npv0v2k8auj2kkgmc9l68mmmzkxvpcnzd3feyygp8hw6wq2qup6f97zfjlm2hzhlk4a9veegqstahde"
}
```

Comment: Could you share the remainder of the `listpeers` command? It could be that the channel simply wasn't confirmed yet. The peer may also have been temporarily disconnected during the payment attempt.

Comment: @cdecker Hi. Thanks. I added the result of listpeers. but what should I see...?

Comment: Could you try again? That channel looks to me like it should just work.

Comment: ok I will do it again now.

Comment: @cdecker It worked. Thank you so much for taking your time. (I added the detail as "update 3")